# Subtract 1 from total if check box is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say you have a checkbox and beside it you show any numbers, be it 10 and when user clicks on the checkbox then that 10 becomes 9 but if unchecks then it again becomes 10.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="credits" name="credits" <?php echo $checked;?> /> (10) Credit
```

The value of credit would be fetched from database.

Comment: You can user jQuery to update the value in UI, if you want to update the database then you could use ajax call in the checkbox change event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(function () {
  $('#credits').change(function () {
    var currentValue = parseInt($('#credit-amount').text());
    var newValue = currentValue + ($(this).prop('checked') ? -1 : 1);
    $('#credit-amount').text(newValue);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="credits" name="credits" /> (<span id="credit-amount">10</span>) Credit
```

Comment: thanks you so much @smarx for your help.

Comment: @smrax on submit the checked value returns back to the default. how to fix that bro?

Comment: Of course it does... how you "fix" that depends on what you want the checkbox to actually do. (E.g. you could send that state to the server and have it set the checked state on page load to whatever it stored, or you could use a cookie or local storage to just remember something locally in that browser.) You'll need to decide what behavior you want. As a side note, I find being called "bro" a little offensive. (This will vary from culture to culture.)

Comment: sorry about that. well how could that be achieved via cookie?